# Evaluating multiple processes and sort the results

Tags: sorting, hold

I would like to evaluate the code below and sort the two parameters {f2, M}. Say that i runs from 1 to 10

```
Clear[C1, f1, f2];i = 3;f1 = i;f2 := 1 + i^2;Eq1 := C1 f1 - C1 f2 ;Consts = Solve[Eq1 == i, {C1}];C1 := Evaluate[Consts[[1, 1, 2]]];M = Integrate[C1 x^2, {x, 0, 5}]
```

Comment: Your code is a little funny, with lots of redundancy. Does this do what you want? `Table[Sort@{1 + f1^2, 
   Integrate[f1/(f1 - (1 + f1^2)) x^2, {x, 0, 5}]}, {f1, 1, 10}]`.

Comment: Thanx @march, in fact, my code is very complicated where I have a system of Eqs. that numerically solved, but here I was trying to simplify the problem.So, what I I would like to know is how I can evaluate the whole block repeatedly for _i_ and sort the results

Comment: `Table[
 f1 = i;
 f2 := 1 + i^2;
 Eq1 := C1 f1 - C1 f2;
 Consts = First@Solve[Eq1 == i, {C1}];
 Sort@{f2, M = Integrate[C1 x^2 /. Consts, {x, 0, 5}]}
 , {i, 1, 10}]`.

Comment: Thanx @march, just one more thing, how can I keep the order of parameters inside the sort? because the output is mixed such that {f2,m} and few of them {m,f2} ?!

Comment: You said you wanted to sort them. Just remove the Sort@ part of the code. If that doesn’t do what you want, more details with sample input and output is necessary.